# ms access: Count, DISTINCT and Where clause. Different results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two queries which should return the same result. Does anyone know why I get different results?

```
SELECT Count(Column1) AS UniqueValues
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Column1, Column2 FROM Table1)  AS T
WHERE Column2 is not null;
```

and I also have this query

```
SELECT Count(Column1) As UniqueValues
FROM ( SELECT Distinct Column1 From Table1) As T;
```

usually i have 5 types of Column 2 and the total combined number of all 5 queries differs from the total result i get from using only column 1. Does anyone know why?

Thank you!

Comment: When you run just the inner query how do the results differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SELECT DISTINCT Column1, Column2` will include all unique combinations of the two columns.  So if a given value in `Column1` occurs together with two different values in `Column2`, the subquery will return two records where it previously returned only one record.

Your line `SELECT Count(Column1) As UniqueValues` will return 2 in this case, not 1.  Yes, both records have the same value for `Column1`, but the `COUNT()` function doesn't care about that.  You're giving a name of `UniqueValues`, but there is nothing here that requires the values in `Column1` to be unique.